# POJO class mismatch

Tags: kotlin

I have the following class **User** that extends the `BaseResponse` class. I 
am getting a type mismatch error:
Required => **`String`**
Found => **`String.Companion`**

for return **apiKey**

```
package com.touchsides.rxjavanetworking.network.model

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

class User: BaseResponse()
{

    @SerializedName("api_key")
    val apiKey = String

    fun getApiKey(): String
    {
        return  apiKey
    }
}

abstract class BaseResponse(var error: String?=null)
{


}
```

How is the current implementation of this wrong

Comment: Simple typo `val apiKey = String` where you meant `val apiKey: String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A complete answer is that your code should look like this:

```
class User: BaseResponse()
{
    @SerializedName("api_key")
    lateinit var apiKey: String  // must be set by something before being read
}

abstract class BaseResponse(var error: String?=null) {
}
```

You do not need a default value for the `apiKey` property if you intend to set it via deserialization later, if not then you should also add a default value as below.  The `getApiKey()` method is removed because you do not need that in Kotlin, all properties have [automatically generated getters](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#getters-and-setters) built-in and by adding your own you would end up with a conflict between the generated getter and the one you manually created (*two methods with the same name, same signature*).

If you do need a default value for `apiKey` then stay with a `var` so that deserialization can work (if you intend to do that) and add a default empty string or make it a nullable string and set it to `null`.

```
class User: BaseResponse()
{
    @SerializedName("api_key")
    var apiKey: String = ""     // if you want a default regardless, or make it nullable and null
}

abstract class BaseResponse(var error: String?=null) {}
```

Answer (score 2):

You used `=` instead `:` while declaration of `api_key` `(apiKey = String)`. Which actually means you are initialising `api_key` with `String.Companion` Object.

And you don't need to create `getApiKey()` (getter) method as by default you will have getter method for your properties.

```
class User : BaseResponse() {

    @SerializedName("api_key")
    var apiKey: String? = null
        private set

}

abstract class BaseResponse(var error: String? = null)
```

in fact you can use `data class` for this purposes

```
data class User(@SerializedName("api_key") val apiKey: String):BaseResponse()

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Gson().fromJson<User>("{\"api_key\":\"my api key\"}", User::class.java).let {
        println(it.apiKey)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You're stuck with the way Java do things. In kotlin when defining `Getter` and `Setter`, you don't have to write them yourself. Once you declare a variable, both methods would be automatically created.

**EDIT**: So delete the getter in your POJO class.

Comment: @Jayson Minard You're wrong. I used it in one of my projects and it works fine. On second thought, explain why it won't work for the OP.

Comment: It depends on how the deserialization works, if it uses reflection and grabs the field and does something dangerous without going through a setter then it might stuff a value in there.  Many deserializers will not, they will see it as read-only and not set it.   Kotlin specific ones sure won't.  Serialization would work fine, which is going the other direction.

Comment: So you can rely on luck of some Java code doing reflection stuffing, or you could make it `lateinit var apiKey: String` and use the mechanism intended for this specific use case.